# How to read data from a device at the Kernel Level?

Tags: android, kernel, device-driver

I have this class project in which I have to read data in the kernel scheduler from an input device. I have to write this device and read it at the kernel level. How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific problems did you encounter? Post the code which is causing you problems and explain what you tried to fix it. "How can this be done?" - questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow by the way...

Comment: What do you mean by "kernel level"? Is there a device driver (making it possible to talk to the device by means of a file, e.g. something like `/dev/xxx`)? Note however, that you will probably need root permissions in order to access something like this.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I have no clue where to start with this, I tried searching but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: @KarolBabioch Concerning the /dev/xxx, I only know how to write device drivers as modules and manually launch them through uml but i don't know how to do this when the kernel starts

Comment: You could always use a simple script to load a module during boot, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: @KarolBabioch yess, thank you for that answer.
and, do you know of any way i could read data from that device In the kernel scheduler?

Comment: I'm still not getting the whole scope of what you are actually trying to do? What information do you need from the scheduler? What does this have to do with your driver? Do you need to interact with your driver or the scheduler? Or both?

Comment: @KarolBabioch the idea is: when the scheduler is invoked I want to read a value from the device and based on that value, kill processes in the queue or stop from running. thanks again for the help :)